# jquery && operator doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, operators, toggle, show-hide

I have a issue with the following piece of code.
Button to toggle a div.
Inside the toggle div a have a few other divs and other elements.

```
$(function () {
    $('#btn').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('clicked toggle');
        $('#Popover').toggle();
        if ($('#Popover:visible').length == 0) {
            $('#Popover').hide();
        } else {
            $('#Popover').show();
        }
    });
});

$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    var container = $('#Popover');
    var trigger = $('#btn');

    if (($(e.target).closest(trigger).length === 0) && ($(e.target).closest(container).length === 0)) {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

It work great the button toggles the div. When I click outside the button / togglediv the togglediv hides.

**The issue is when is click on a div inside the toggle div the div also hides.**

it seems that the && operator doesnt work or is there something else wrong with my code.

Maybe it is a postback issue
The following code is the onclick method for a div (div id="hourInc") inside the toggle div

```
 $('#hourInc').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var hour = $('#cn_TimeHour').val();
        if (hour < 12) {
            hour = (hour * 1) + 1;
        }
        else {
            hour = 0;
        }
        $('#cn_TimeHour').val(("0" + hour).slice(-2));
        setTime();
    });
```

Comment: `&&` operator doesn't relates to jQuery at all. Something wrong with conditions. Try to debug them one by one.

Comment: Can you provide full demo of the issue with html?

Comment: Provide relevant HTML markup in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback

The issue where the click event.
I inserted return false at the bottom of these methods.

That's seems to work

Answer (score 0):

The "==" acts slightly differently to "===".

The identity (===) operator behaves identically to the equality (==) operator except no type conversion is done, and the types must be the same to be considered equal.

Reference: Javascript Tutorial: Comparison Operators

The == operator will compare for equality after doing any necessary type conversions. The === operator will not do the conversion, so if two values are not the same type === will simply return false. It's this case where === will be faster, and may return a different result than ==. In all other cases performance will be the same.

Comment: Why that? `.length` returns a number

Comment: In case of .length property in javascript it would be really weird if they were different type.